# How to share raw input given in one file with another file in python

Tags: python

I want raw input given in one file to be used in another file.
For this I defined all variables in a `global_dec.py` file . Then modified the value of these variables in `main_file.py` and when I got printed these variables in another file `partfile.py` then variables having integer and string value got modified but the raw input is not giving value given in `main_fily.py`

Code is as follow:

global_dec.py:

```
 class common(object):

  a=0
  x="x inside global class "
  y=raw_input("  enter input for the global class: ")
```

main_file.py:

```
  from global_dec import common

  common.x = "  x changed inside main file "
  common.a=1

  def dummy():
   print "dummy"

  def main():
   print " main"

  if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

partfile.py:

```
 from global_dec import common

 def main():

  print "x:  "+common.x, "  y:  "+common.y, "  a: "+str(common.a)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question right you want to be able to do the following...

```
$ python main_file.py
 enter input for the global class: something
main
$ python partfile.py
 enter input for the global class: something else
x: x inside global class y: something else a: 0
```

If that is the case it is not possible because the python process ends and all values that are stored in memory for the app are thrown away. Change your `main` function in `main_file.py` to be exactly like the one in `partfile.py` and you will see that even the `x` and `a` values may change but they do not persist. The only way to have persistent data between running python processes is to use a database.

Probably a better way of showing this would be for your `main_file.py` to look like so...

```
from global_dec import common

common.x = 'i have changed'
common.a += 1

def main():
    print "x: " + common.x + " a: " + str(common.a) + " y: " + common.y
```

Then run it twice and it should look like this.

```
$ python main_file.py
 enter input for the global class: blah
x: I have changed a: 1 y: blah
$ python main_file.py
 enter input for the global class: blah
x: I have changed a: 1 y: blah
```

Notice `a` will always be 1 since when it is imported at the beginning of the process it is 0 then is incremented to 1 and when the process finishes the variable is dumped from memory. I hope that helps